# Ruby on Rails: Model with different implementations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, inheritance

I have in my Rails application a bunch of different providers that each have a custom implementation.

The providers are all stored in the DB, and the implementation to chose should be decided when loading the object from the DB depending upon its data.

Here is a solution I've come up with to do this.

/app/models/provider.rb

```
class Provider < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name

  validates :name, :presence => true

  after_find :load_implementation

  # Loads the correct implementation for the provider
  def load_implementation
    case self.name
    when "FirstProvider"
      extend FirstProvider
    when "SecondProvider"
      extend SecondProvider
    else
      raise "No implementation for provider #{self.name}"
    end
  end
end
```

/lib/first_provider.rb

```
module FirstProvider
  def foo
    puts "foo"
  end
end
```

/lib/second_provider.rb

```
module SecondProvider
  def foo
    puts "bar"
  end
end
```

And here is how I use it:

```
Providers.all.each do |p|
  p.foo
end
```

Do you see any problem using this solution? Can you think of a more appropriate way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to have a look to Rails' [Single Inheritance Table](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#label-Single+table+inheritance) mechanism.

You would still have *x* class to create (where *x* is the number of provider you have with their `foo` implementation). Those classes would all inherits from a main `Provider` ActiveRecord class.

However, you won't have to write a method such as `load_implementation`. The provider's type would be stored in a the database column "*type*" of the database table "*providers*".

Comment: That's what I was looking for. Should the implementation files be located in `app/models/` as well?

Comment: Yes they should be located there !

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason You don't want to use ActiveRecord single table inheritance ?

```
class FirstProvider < Provider
  def foo
    puts 'foo'
  end
end
```